# Troubleshooting Brown's NAO Driver

Tags: nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I can't seem to get the Brown University Nao driver to work. I'm using the new Nao h25 model, with NaoQi SDK version 1.10.

When I run (locally on the robot) ./eyes, I am told "Could not get shared memory" (same issue as on [http://code.google.com/p/brown-ros-pkg/issues/detail?id=7]). When I run control.py, I get SOAP errors of the form "setVolume not a member of tts" and "setStiffness not a member of motion" ...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10972/troubleshooting-brown%27s-nao-driver/) by [Nick Armstrong-Crews](https://answers.ros.org/users/885/nick-armstrong-crews/) on ROS Answers with karma: 481 on 2011-08-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nick Armstrong-Crews](https://answers.ros.org/users/885/nick-armstrong-crews/) on 2011-08-22**:
Update: was able to get nodes to run such that I can see the /eyes topic, although it is never published to.  I had to add a symlink from /opt/naoqi/modules/lib to /opt/naoqi/lib, which fixed error for eyes node; and I had to comment out setVolume, setStiffness commands in control.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Got camera feed over ROS working! But not using Brown's driver. For details, see last comment for ticket http://answers.ros.org/question/1864/nao-teleop-and-camera-feed?answer=3277

---

Originally posted by [Nick Armstrong-Crews](https://answers.ros.org/users/885/nick-armstrong-crews/) with karma: 481 on 2011-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1